# Permission denied reading error in CodeBlocks?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

When I try to build and run my code, CodeBlocks gives the following error:

Error: can't open C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4x6bY8.s for reading: Permission denied

I am using MinGW compiler. I have tried reinstalling codeblocks, running codeblocks as administrator, and restarting my computer

Comment: Do you have some weird antivirus software?

Comment: @melpomene no antivirus.

Comment: Does that folder exist? Does the mentioned file exist? If it does exist does the date / time make sense?